# Decompose fails because time-series period is set incorrectly

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to plot a decomposed time series, but running into an error:

> Error in decompose(ts_ret) : time series has no or less than 2 periods`.

I am forcing the time series to a fixed period that is higher than 2.

1. Why does the ts think the period is less than 2?
2. Shouldn't the period be set automatically based on the time intervals in the data? (which are daily)

---

```
rm(list=ls())
library(jsonlite)
library(xts)
item.id<-18
eve.url<-paste0("http://eve-marketdata.com/api/item_history2.json?char_name=demo&region_ids=10000002&type_ids=",item.id,"&days=100")
eve.data<-data.frame(fromJSON(txt=eve.url))$emd.row
eve.data$date<-as.POSIXct(eve.data$date,format="%Y-%m-%d",tz="EST")
xxx<-xts(as.numeric(eve.data[,"avgPrice"]),eve.data$date)
colnames(xxx)<-"trit"
ts_ret<-ts(xxx,frequency=52) #but Im setting the periods here..... 
plot(decompose(ts_ret))
```

Comment: Please offer solutions for how I can improve the post if you downvote it. I am happy to make changes.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but: 1) include package dependencies; 2) what is `ans` in second to last line? In any case, you can't turn a daily series into a weekly one with `ts(..., frequency = 52)`. You need to reduce the data in a prior step.

Comment: Thanks, I included libraries and updated the code (thats what I get for adapting my code for an example)

Comment: The data returned from that url only covers a couple of months, and `decompose` is expecting data that spans at least a couple of years, so it can look for (annual) seasonality in it. If you want to look for cyclical trends on shorter periods, like days of the week, you need to use a different approach. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1207/period-detection-of-a-generic-time-series and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/209426/predictions-from-bsts-model-in-r-are-failing-completely for a couple of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ufelder pointed out my dataset was too small to look at seasonal decomposition because I only had a few months of data (measured hourly), but not an entire seasons worth (which is 4 months). To fix this I had to modify the period of the dataset to once per day by using `ts(xxx,frequency=365)` so decompose would compare across days, not seasons.